# maven-jaxb2-plugin Fail to Generate WSDL Schema

Tags: maven, plugins, wsdl, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm trying to generate a schema by using WSDL URL, but failed and got this error code:

> Execution default of goal
>   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed:
>   Plugin org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not
>   be resolved: org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.12.3,
>   org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.2.11,
>   org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11,
>   org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2:
>   Failure to transfer
>   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.12.3 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.12.3 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
>   (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate:default:generate-sources)

My POM :

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>soap.test</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I tried to downgrade the version but I still got the same error.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem with your local maven repository. Locate your repository folder and delete everything under `org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the version.
    
        
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-maven-plugin
            
            
                org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2
                maven-jaxb2-plugin
                ***0***
                
                    
                        
                            generate
                        
                    
                
                
                    /src/main/resources/wsdl
                    
                        *.wsdl

Comment: REMOVE VERSION, IT'S WORKING